# Safety_Question - undecidable to prove a system is safe

Tags: security, computer-science

This question is about the "safety question" of lecture 2 of  iTunes U security course at 
https://itunes.apple.com/us/itunes-u/computer-science-foundations/id389259109

and @37:00 there is a proof that  the problem of proving a system is safe is undecidable. The argument is that the problem is undecidable because  a protection system exactly simulates a TM, and if we defined a "halting right"  then it follows that the question of whether the TM ever  leaks the "halting right" is undecidable .

What is a concrete example of a "halting right"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It talks about the `HRU`(Harrison-Ruzzo-Ullman) model.

- we represent a state as triple Q=(S,O,A)

where:

*S*-set of subjects

*O*-set of objects

and *A*-the access matrix.

main access modes are: `read,write,append,execute and own`(means that the subject is the owner of the object - that means he has admin authorization on the object).

in the original paper of `HRU` (without Denning's extensions),
Informally, a system is unsafe if some subject can get some right r on object o, (which presumably we did not want to happen).  This is called a `leak`. 
The formal definition says:

`a command α leaks some generic right r from configuration  Q = (S, O, A), if α when run on Q, can execute the primitive operation enter r into A[s,o] 
which did not previously contain r.`

then comes the claim that protection system exactly simulates a TM and if TM enters state qf (finite), then *right has leaked*, If *safety question decidable*, then represent TM and determine if qf leaks implies *halting problem decidable* (which is known to be NP-Hard problem).

hopes it make it clear,
Cheers.

Comment: Yes, and reading a chapter from M. Bishop's book also helped.